# Same query, different result after removing USE DatabaseName GO

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

My function `GetProductDesc` (when called) returns a different result after commenting out `USE DatabaseName GO`. I don't even know where to start debugging this. The pictures tell the story. I had to blur out a lot but you can see that the results are clearly different. Keep in mind that the pictures are not the function code, they are calling the function `GetProductDesc`

[image: Result one with USE DatabaseName GO]

[image: Result two without USE DatabaseName GO]

So strange. Any suggestions? I have an expert helping me later today but I had to share.

EDIT:
The function uses another lookup table in the same database. There is no Top or Order By clause. It calculates the product description based on the input components (numbers). It will return a different result if the input numbers are different, but here the input numbers are the same!
The function has been in place and working for over 5 years. I believe the problem started at about the time the version of SQL Server was updated recently.

EDIT 2 with partial answer:
The problem is caused by `@@RowCount`. It appears to be a breaking change caused by our recent migration to SQL Server 2019 although I haven't found the problem documented. The function returns a different product description based on `@@RowCount` following a `Select` statement. Internally the function does something like this:

```
SELECT Fields FROM Table WHERE Field = @Variable

IF @@Rowcount = 1
   Return ProdDesc1
ELSE
   Return ProdDesc2
```

After the SQL Server migration `@@RowCount` here was different depending on whether

```
USE DatabaseName
GO
```

was present.

The solution was to replace `@@Rowcount` with a variable `@RowCount`. This new code works:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT = 0

SELECT Fields, @RowCount = @RowCount + 1 
FROM Table WHERE Field = @Variable

IF @RowCount = 1
   Return ProdDesc1
ELSE
   Return ProdDesc2
```

If you have SQL Server 2019 installed try this to recreate the problem:

```
USE Master
GO

Select @@ROWCOUNT
```

The result here is `@@ROWCOUNT = 0`

Now comment out the two top lines:

```
--USE Master
--GO

Select @@ROWCOUNT
```

The result is now `@@ROWCOUNT = 1`

Anybody know why?

Comment: What does the function do?

Comment: Does the function have tables from different dbs?

Comment: And what exactly does "your funtion" do? Does it use TOP without an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: The function uses another lookup table in the same database. It calculates the product description based on the input components (numbers). It will return a different result if the input numbers are different, but here the input numbers are the same!

Comment: There is no Top or Order By clause.

Comment: Without code, there is little to offer but guessing.

Comment: The function has been in place and working for over 5 years. I believe the problem started at about the time the version of SQL Server was updated.

Comment: Please show the function, the relevant tables, and the full query, please share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. You can obfuscate the names if necessary, and the plans via SentryOne Plan Explorer.

Comment: Let's give some guesses, seeing as we have absolutely no info to go on. In order of likelihood: `TOP` or window functions with no `ORDER BY`, different `DATEFORMAT` setting, different default collation, different language setting, different ANSI defaults.

Comment: You have no "function" as posted. That term has a specific meaning within tsql - using it for a different purpose is misleading. Without context it is impossible to know what your code "returns" and to whom it returns. You cannot use the USE statement in a procedure or function nor is GO a valid tsql statement (it's a batch separator) so ... I give up.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The pictures are calling the function from a new query window. I have not shown the function code because there is too much code in there that has nothing to do with the problem. Now that I have fixed the problem I'm simply wondering why, in a new SQL 2019 query window: Select @@ROWCOUNT returns a different result if it is preceded by USE DatabaseName Go.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=58d9dd81ca362f0cbe9af19862ce82c4), not on my local instance either

Comment: Our migration to SQL Server 2019 must've caused this problem. In a new query window I get @@ROWCOUNT = 1, but when I add USE DatabaseName GO on top I get @@ROWCOUNT = 0. That strange behavior caused my function to return the wrong result. Now I'm wondering what other problems it's causing that haven't come to light. We have a pretty massive database code base. Time for a support call.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [SQL Server 2019 cumulative update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d) from Microsoft that fixes this problem.